# Is the wallet address and generated account address the same?

Tags: wallet, account

I have already looked at these questions / answers:
[Question1](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/multiple-accounts-in-the-same-wallet), [Question2](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/how-to-generate-a-monero-wallet-address-with-the-api), [Answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10724/are-there-separate-view-keys-for-each-account-in-a-monero-wallet), and now have the following understanding about Monero wallets, accounts and addresses:

- We can ***create wallet*** which generates a **.keys** file and has a **wallet address, wallet password, wallet menmonic.**
- We can ***create account*** with/without a **label** which generates one **address** for that account and **account_index.**
- We can create subaddresses using ***create address***, which requires **account_index** and it will generate an **address** and **address_index**.

I still have some confusion about:

1. Is the account index automatically generated with wallet generation?
2. How is the wallet related to an account and how is an account related to address/subaddress?

I have already read all the documents regarding this I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. A wallet starts life with one account (account index 0), which has one address (your primary wallet address).
2. A wallet has one or more accounts and accounts have one or more addresses.